# Mysql password warning in bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, unix

I am currently running mysql through bash. However it returns the error:

```
Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

What are the secure ways to accomplish this? How can I properly call the mysql without this warning?

```
#!/bin/bash/
user=test
password=test
database=test

mysql --user='$user' --password='$password' --database='$database' --execute='DROP DATABASE $user; CREATE DATABASE $database;'
```

Result

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

Comment: Where do you use the `ffmpeg_path` variable?

Comment: I don't think the error has anything to do with the user of the variable.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I made the necessary changes.

Comment: Does the warning go away if you use `<(/home/yourusername/bin/ffprobe -i "$file" -show_format -v quiet | grep '.=.')`?

Comment: @Barmar, I tried that and it still gives the same error.

Comment: So the error has nothing to do with assigning a variable. I don't see a password in the code in the question, though, so I'm not sure why it's complaining about that.

Comment: @Barmar, it executes and gives a result. It is just that warning that is mysterious. In the past I had ffmpeg installed differently therfore i just called `ffmpeg -i ..` and it worked. Deleted that and compiled the source and now when I call it specifically as shown above it gives error. Calling `ffmpeg` straight from the command line works well.

Comment: If you run that exact command manually you don't get that error? What about with the variable? What do you get as output if you stick `set -x` at the top of that script? How are you running this script? That final slash on the shebang `#!` line is incorrect also.

Comment: @EtanReisner you are right apparently it was an issue with the shebang.

Comment: You should probably update the post with an edit indicating that through psychic debugging pasabaporaqui was able to determine the real problem here and include the snippet of code that was **actually** causing the warning under discussion.

Comment: @EtanReisner I will do so.

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student Where is the update? Currently both the title and the code are totally unrelated to the actual problem, so I'm downvoting the question.

Comment: @Barmar, restricted access to my pc, finally i was now able to update my question more accordingly to the issue i had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You command opens a mysql session passing as argument the mysql password (I see this message tenths at day).

Comment: Oh yes, this was also an issue. It was below a few lines below the script shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the password on the command line, create a `~/.my.cnf` file, and put the password in there. The file can supply default values for any of the command line options. For instance, you can put this in it:

```
[client]
database = test
user = test
password = test
```

Then you can just run:

```
mysql --execute='DROP DATABASE $user; CREATE DATABASE $database;'
```

Make sure the file's permissions are restricted, so unauthorized users can't see the password.